# Surface described by ${\bf r^\top A r + b^\top r}=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

I was asked to describe the surface described by

$${\bf r}^\top {\bf A} {\bf r} + {\bf b}^\top {\bf r} = 1,$$

where $3 \times 3$ positive definite matrix ${\bf A}$ and vector $\bf b$ are given.

My intuition tells me that it is a rotated ellipsoid with a centre that is off the origin. However, I am told to show this via the substitution ${\bf r} = {\bf x} + {\bf a}$, with $\bf a$ being a constant vector, and dictate the conditions on this vector to obtain a new quadric surface ${\bf x}^\top{\bf A}{\bf x} = C$. However, upon substitution, I get a ridiculously messy answer involving combinations of position and constant vectors. Is there a trick I am missing out on? Thank you!

Comment: Depending on eigenvalues of $\bf A$ it can be an ellipsoid, hyperboloid, paraboloid, two lines (planes) and not so much more.

Comment: Assume it has positive eigenvalues, sorry for not being clear!

Comment: Oh wait I did say positive definite 

Comment: Strictly positive eigenvalues will guarantee an ellipsoid I think.

Comment: Ah yep I see now in answer it says positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: for convenience we use $2b$ instead of $b$.

$$(x+a)^TA(x+a)+2b^T(x+a)=x^TAx+a^TAx+x^TAa+a^TAa+b^Tx+2b^Ta.$$

Notice that by symmetry of $A$, $x^TAa=a^TAx$. Collecting all the $x$ terms,

$$(2a^TA+2b^T)x$$ can be cancelled with the choice

$$a=-A^{-1}b.$$

Then

$$C=1-a^TAa-2b^Ta=1+b^TA^{-1}b>1.$$

(As $A$ is positive definite, it is invertible. Note that this is a matrix version of the "complete the square" paradigm.)

---

Going further, you can diagonalize the matrix and write, in the basis defined by the Eigenvectors

$$y^T\Lambda y=C$$

or

$$\lambda_0u^2+\lambda_1v^2+\lambda_2w_2=C.$$

As the three Eigenvalues are positive,

$$(\sqrt\lambda_0u)^2+(\sqrt\lambda_1v)^2+(\sqrt\lambda_2w)^2=C$$ describes a stretched sphere.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I am told to show this via the substitution
>   ${\bf r} = {\bf x} + {\bf a}$, with $\bf a$ being a constant vector, and dictate the
>   conditions on this vector to obtain a new quadric surface 
>   ${\bf x}^\top{\bf A}{\bf x} = C$.

Following your advice:
\begin{align}
1 
&= r^\top A r + b^\top r \\
&= (x + a)^\top A(x+a) + b^\top(x+a) \\
&= x^\top A x + \underbrace{x^\top A a + a^\top A x + b^\top x}_{f(x)} + a^\top A a +  b^\top a
\end{align}
We need to choose $a$ such that the terms depending on $x$ vanish:
$$
0 = x^\top A a + a^\top A x + b^\top x
$$
The "positive definite" property holds for symmetric matrices, which fulfill
$$
A^\top = A
$$
so we have
$$
x^\top A a = x^\top A^\top a = (A x)^\top a = a^\top A x
$$
using symmetry and the rules for transposition, which gives
$$
0 = a^\top A x + a^\top A x + b^\top x = (2 a^\top A + b^\top) x
$$
so for all vectors $x$ to hold, we need
$$
0 = 2 a^\top A + b^\top \iff \\
0 = 0^\top = 2 A^\top a + b = 2 A a + b \iff \\
a = -(A^{-1}b)/2
$$
Justification of the last step:

For a positive definite matrix $A$ all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are positive, so its determinant (the product of its eigenvalues) is positive as well, and thus non-vanishing. Therefore it has an inverse $A^{-1}$.

So we end up with
$$
x^\top A x = C
$$
where
\begin{align}
C 
&= 1 - a^\top A a - b^\top a \\
&= 1 - (A^{-1} b)^\top A (A^{-1} b) / 4 + b^\top (A^{-1} b)/2 \\
&= 1 - b^\top (A^{-1})^\top b / 4 + b^\top A^{-1} b /2 \\
&= 1 - b^\top (A^\top)^{-1} b / 4 + b^\top A^{-1} b /2 \\
&= 1 - b^\top A^{-1} b / 4 + b^\top A^{-1} b /2 \\
&= 1 + \underbrace{b^\top A^{-1} b}_{> 0} / 4
\end{align}
because matrix transposition and inverting operations commute and using symmetry again.

$A^{-1}$ has eigenvalues $1/\lambda_i$ which are all positive as well, so $A^{-1}$ is positive definite too. This assures that the constant number $C$ is positive and we deal with an [ellipsoid surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#As_quadric).

Here is an example for
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\quad
b =
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\ -1 \\ -3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
[image: Example]

**Update:**

Here is a [link](https://ggbm.at/cMbcMAhN) to an interactive version of the above scene.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the informative diagram! What’s the best way to physically interpret $a$ and $b$ given the constraint?

Comment: $r = x + a \iff x = r - a$ is a translation of the coordinate system, where $a$ is the new origin. $b$ seems not to have a nice interpretation. I am adding a link to an interactive version of the above graphics, you will see that it has several effects. The interesting properties IMHO are the half axes of the ellipsoid and then the affine transformations (translation, rotation, scaling).